# Wrapping div around floated content without the wrapper getting same width as it's own parent

Tags: html, css

My issue is that I need to be able to center the div containing all the floated elements inside another div. This needs to be dynamic.

I've managed to get such a div, but my last remaining issue is when you add enough elements so it becomes two rows instead of one. Nomatter how much space there's left the inner container stretches out the full width instead of just being as wide as its children.

http://jsfiddle.net/qsAUk/16/

```
<div id="outer">
    <div id="inner">
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
    </div>
</div>

#outer
{
    background-color: blue;
    text-align: center;
}

#inner
{
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: red;
}

.box
{
    background-color: black;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    float: left;
}
```

Illustrates my problem quite fast.

I have an outer div of a certain width.

I have an inner div wich should be the same width as it's children so I can center it inside the outer. Right now it has the same width as the outer div that's wrapping it.

Answer (score 0):

to center the div containing all the floated elements (i think you are talking about the #outer) add this line to your css :

```
#outer {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

this is your fiddle updated : http://jsfiddle.net/qsAUk/6/

Comment: Well it's really about centering the elements inside dynamically while still having them float from left to right. 

I will edit my post to clarify and remove that second example. Think it will just confuse what I'm looking for.